# Perl, run SQL select Oracle and SQL Server and large recordset and import it straight into an array

Tags: sql, sql-server, arrays, oracle, perl

Seeking some advice here.

I need to write a program that fetches between 6,000 and 8,000 items of data from a column in an Oracle 11 DB and SQL Server database 2008 DB.

I do not want to get one row at a time, that would take forever.

My question, is it possible to send the SELECT results straight into an array in PERL? Note I am trying to avoid going row by row in the Perl program to get the resultset.
In addition, if anyone has any other ideas on a better way to do this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a [selectcol_arrayref](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/DBI#selectcol_arrayref) DBI method that does this, but internally it just does the loop you want to avoid.

But I think you are overestimating the time such a loop will take; it won't be particularly noticeable.  (6000 to 8000 inserts might be a little slow, but fetching a single column from 6000 to 8000 rows should be quite speedy.)